# Can not vagrant up virtual box - The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine 'default' - /dev/vboxdrv does not exist

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Now I am facing an error about vagrant and virtualbox. I can't up my vagrant. while I up my vagrant it is show error below.

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

After I run "VBoxManage --version" it shows

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.10_Ubuntur138449
```

Does anyone used to know this error, could you help me to fix this problem. I already search a lot but, cannot apply the solution. Sometimes they talk about `disable secure boot`. Thank you in advance !!

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Vagrant 2.2.9
- Version 6.1.10_Ubuntu r138449